# Chinese name for a money belt

Tags: word-requests

What is Chinese for a money belt?  I mean the kind of linen or silk packet on an elastic band that you wear under your clothes, to hold money.

Chinese manufacturers often offer them online as "cash money holiday belts" but I have not found a bi-lingual cite with the original Chinese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [防盗|贴身|隐形] (小)腰(带)包.

Looking for any one of these terms on [Taobao](http://s.taobao.com/search?q=%E9%98%B2%E7%9B%97%E8%85%B0%E5%8C%85), you'll see how it is commonly referred to:
[image]

Comment: A version using words I know better is  旅行安全钱包。